# Laravel's Eloquent table 'inheritence' with parents

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel model `acl_groups` that has a JSON column `inherits`. What should I do, the "laravel way" to query the inherited groups when checking if a group can do something? The rights are stored in another JSON column, allow/deny so I can just do a `in_array` to check a single group if they have access.

Comment: what do you mean by query the inherited groups?
can you provide sample code showing how you are doing it  and how you  want to do it?

Answer (score 0):

On your `model` you can set a `getter`

```
public function getInheritsAttribute($v)
    {
        return $v ? json_decode($v, true) : [];
    }
```

OR
if you dont want a getter you can try a pseudo getter

```
public function getPseudoAttribute()
        {
            return $this->inherits ? json_decode($this->inherits, true) : [];
        }
```

Kind of maybe did mistake on second one.

And on other model the same thing
so when you call $item->inherits = you will get an `array`
First you may try to prepare the array like removing same keys or values

and after just check

```
if (array_key_exists('thing_to_check', $item->inherits)) {
    return true;
}
```

This is not a working code, it is just an idea how you can do you.
Take a look at `Cartalyst Sentinel` how they check the permissions for groups and users.

Comment: Well, the inherits array would theoretically contain other group IDs -- how would I efficiently convert those into instances of my group model?